# Python class: how to return instance from list that satisfies __eq__()?

Tags: python, class

I am working with a class where `__eq__()` returns True for one particular attribute even if the rest of the attributes aren't equal.

Therefore if `if inst1 in list` is True then I need to be able to extract inst2 from the list where `inst1.attr1 == inst2.attr1` so I can access the other attributes of inst2. How would I go about this? `.remove()` returns None so I can't use that.

A *possible* solution is `for instance in list: ...` but that is useless as my list grows very quickly.

Comment: Why don't you use a dict (attr1 to YourClass) instead?

Comment: @Lesiak can you please elaborate? If you mean maintain a dict instead of a list to save the instances, order is important to me so that won't work.

Comment: There is no way to search an unsorted list without looking at each element - you probably need a different data structure. Write down all required operations and required asymptotic complexity - thus giving us a way to suggest desired data structure. Estimate number of elems you need to support. BTW, dicts are ordered in Python (in insertion order)